# How should I set CALLBACK URI

Tags: android, foursquare

I'm developing an Android app with Foursquare API. As stated [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth), after a Foursquare user logs in, he will be redirected to app callback page and I can have the ACCESS TOKEN to provide other services. The CALLBACK URL is supposed to be specified by me along with  CLIENT ID and CLIENT SECRET. My question is : how should I set the CALLBACK URL? The fact is I do get the ACCESS TOKEN but what I should present to user then provided that the user log-in page is a WebView in an Acitivity rather than a Dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this Post for Authenticatiteon in Foursquare and Call back after successful login

[Authentication using Foursqaure and Call back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845361/foursquare-integration-in-android)

Give some Dummy call back url in the call back url field of your Application's Settings page.

Comment: direct user to another activity ... I should've thought of that. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

It has been my experience to use: myapp://connect for that parameter of your callback set in your consumer. What I don't like is the Download/Welcome URL. This should not be needed but it is though, and if you open an auth window for opt-in, then you get a web page to load that gets you further away from the App, as in Android and then if you are using the Splash Screen to Auth, leads to a non - referral to the main part of the app. IMHO This should be not included with the signon screen, or disabled.