# After twitter login web page not found error

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying for twitter example.http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application i got example from this link.I am getting twitter login page but after authentication it should be redirected to some url.I am using web view in that web view i gave the url but it is showing web page is not available.
       In preparerequest token activity i gave like this

context.startActivity(new Intent(context,FaceexActivity.class));

```
public class FaceexActivity extends Activity {
WebView browser;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    browser.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
}
}
```

after login when it is going to faceexactivity it is not displaying that web page and showing web page not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am getting twitter login page but after authentication it should  be redirected 
to some url.
```

You should **Redirect to your Application** after successful Authentication  for that make use of **Call back URL field in your Application** , give some Dummy link - **http://www.dummy.com** , Also ensure that you added intents actions in **Manifest  file** and used same call back url inside your Activity.

Rest of things clearly explained in [Android-10 Website](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application)

Comment: <activity android:name=".PrepareRequestTokenActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">>
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="x-latify-oauth-twitter-impress" android:host="callback" />
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>

Comment: i gave this in my manifest file instead of this what should i give

Comment: @user1083266 You should add the same in Constants class file, there you will found callback constants

Comment: i should add my url in constants call back url

Comment: yeah same as you added in Manifest - Also check this post , Four square also have same way of authentication.. I have posted some code check this also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845361/foursquare-integration-in-android

Comment: in my application after login i should go to twitter home page i gave  "http://www.twitter.com?status=" this url please tell me which url i should give to go to home page after login of twitter

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013689/twitter-api-returns-invalid-callback-cannot-authorize/11013812#11013812) helpful, it explains how to get the callback redirecting to work.